# I am using the AWS SES service. We have sent emails, and I would like to track the replies/responses. Is there a way to manage this?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-ses

I am using the AWS SES service. We have sent emails, and I would like to track the replies/responses. so basically how we can store or access the incoming emails.

I have searched in documentation but not able to find, Is there a way to manage this?

Comment: This concept is explained in this doc topic - Email receiving with Amazon SES. You can read about it in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email.html

Answer (score 0):

Just as @smac2020 posted, I am moving it to the Answer section so people would see that this is already answered. Here is a huge documentation about the topic: docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email.html.

To give a brief overview:

1. You register the domain
2. You set up all the necessary configuration for SES (whether to recieve emails on SNS or S3) - dont forget to use only specific regions in AWS, as not everywhere it is possible to receive emails
3. Try it out